# how to find the argument of the division of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

So I have $z=1+i$ and $w=1-\sqrt{3}i$ and $p=\frac{z^6}{w^5}$, also the principal argument is taken to be in the interval $(-\pi ,\pi ]$

Find Arg(p)

I first converted w and z into polar form using eulers notation:

$$z= \sqrt2e^{\frac{1}{4} \pi i}$$ 
$$w= 2e^{\frac{-1}{3}\pi i}$$

then got $w^5= 32 e^{\frac{-5}{3}\pi i}$ and $z^6=8 e^{\frac32 \pi i}$

so

$$p= \frac{8e^{\frac32 \pi i}}{32 e^{-\frac{5}{3}\pi i}} $$

which simplifies to (1/4)*exp((19/6)*Pi*I)

Is the above method correct? and how to I give the final answer of Arg(p) to be in the $(-\pi,\pi]$ interval?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question will be easier to read if you follow the tips at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You proved that an argument is $$\theta=\frac{19}6\pi$$ hence it simply remains to find an integer $n$ such that $$-\pi<\theta+2n\pi\leqslant\pi$$ and then, the principal argument is $$\theta_p=\theta+2n\pi$$ Can you find $n$ and $\theta_p$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you did the right solution and now after doing upto this much you can use the inequality $(-\pi<\theta+2k\pi\leq \pi)$ to find the principal argument of the complex number with such an integer $k$ which makes the angle falls into this region!